# SPARQL , only take specific value from schema and use NaN when not available?

Tags: schema, sparql

I'm doing SPARQL queries on the Swiss company registry database zefix.

One of the companies there is for example:
https://register.ld.admin.ch/zefix/company/182509

As you can see, it has three different entries for schema:identifier . I am only interested in the CompanyUID.

With my current query however, I am getting three rows per company, one for each identifier. I want only the CompanyUID, or if not available nothing.

My current SPARQL is:

```
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX admin: <https://schema.ld.admin.ch/>
SELECT ?company_uri ?name ?company_type ?municipality ?adresse ?locality ?identifier_value ?identifier_name
WHERE {
?company_uri a admin:ZefixOrganisation ;
    schema:name ?name ;
    admin:municipality ?muni_id .
?muni_id schema:name ?municipality .
?company_uri schema:additionalType ?type_id .
?type_id schema:name ?company_type .
?company_uri schema:address ?adr.
?company_uri schema:identifier ?identifier .
?identifier schema:value ?identifier_value .
?identifier schema:name ?identifier_name .
?adr schema:streetAddress ?adresse ;
    schema:addressLocality ?locality .

filter langMatches(lang(?company_type), "de") .

}
LIMIT 10
```

It is giving me three rows per company. I want only one with only the CompanyUID.

Answer (score 0):

The different kinds of identifiers get identified by their `schema:name` value.

Your triple pattern

```
?identifier schema:name ?identifier_name .
```

has a variable (`?identifier_name`) as object, so you ask for all kinds of identifiers.

Instead of using a variable, you can provide the literal you are interested in:

```
?identifier schema:name "CompanyUID" .
```

If a company has no UID, but you want to list the company anyway, enclose the relevant triples in an `OPTIONAL`:

```
OPTIONAL {
  ?company_uri 
    schema:identifier ?identifier .
  ?identifier 
    schema:name "CompanyUID" ;
    schema:value ?identifier_value .
}
```